# Black image for an Image publisher with image_transport

Tags: opencv, cv-bridge, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a node retrieving an image with openCV explained on [this ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages). The image is ten converted into a format suitable for ROS, using CV_bridge functions.

Problem is, there is no image that are published at all on the \camera topic. I tried visualizing it using

> rosrun image_view image_view

But the only thing that appear is a black image. I also tried using rviz camera, but nothing appears; rviz indicate that no image is received:

[image description http://s29.postimg.org/cfodi8klj/Screen_Shot_01_04_15_at_04_44_PM.jpg](http://s29.postimg.org/cfodi8klj/Screen_Shot_01_04_15_at_04_44_PM.jpg)

Here is the code of the publisher:

[code http://s4.postimg.org/z0ucg90vh/Screen_Shot_01_04_15_at_03_42_PM.jpg](http://s4.postimg.org/z0ucg90vh/Screen_Shot_01_04_15_at_03_42_PM.jpg)

And here is the CMakeLists.txt file:

[image description http://s21.postimg.org/flbi6xe07/Screen_Shot_01_04_15_at_04_58_PM.jpg](http://s21.postimg.org/flbi6xe07/Screen_Shot_01_04_15_at_04_58_PM.jpg)

I made a standalone version of the code for openCV, and it display image correctly using imshow. I do believe that the problems lies in the conversion of the openCV image to the format required by the ROS nodes, but I do not know where to look to solve such problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200366/black-image-for-an-image-publisher-with-image_transport/) by [Alexandre.Willame](https://answers.ros.org/users/21108/alexandre.willame/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The source code takes a sample image as argv[1]. I. e. in a folder where a image file like my_photo.jpg is located you have to run it like

```
rosrun image_transport_tutorial my_publisher my_photo.jpg
```

in order for telling it what to publish; otherwise it will just publish an empty image header...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0